# Create gnome terminal profile from current terminal settings

Tags: gnome-terminal

Many of the settings in the gnome terminal profile are numeric, such as the size in rows/columns, but these are configurable by simply resizing the window or setting the zoom level with shortcut keys. Is there a way to create a terminal profile to match an open terminal window? That way I don't have to always count the number of rows and columns when setting up a new desktop, which is basically impossible.

Comment: not Terminal, but Konsole alternative

https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/konsole/konsole/commandreference.html#settings-menu

I like it's
'konsole --tabs-from-file /home.... wherever.
to open mult set tabs from startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no explicit feature provided for this. The vast majority of the profile settings can only be altered via changing the profile anyway, so there would be no point. The size is one of the few exceptions, or probably the only one, where this could be useful.

Querying the size is not "basically impossible" at all. Just run `stty size` or `echo $LINES $COLUMNS`. Then copy these numbers over to your profile settings whenever you're "setting up a new desktop", which I presume doesn't happen very often.

(Zoom level is different. There's no zoom level option in the profile settings, there's only a font size setting, and the two aren't exactly the same. A font such as `Monospace 10` with a zoom level of let's say `144%` probably doesn't map exactly into any of the available `Monospace <some integer number>` choices.)